# Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';' with regards to createstripeuser

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to call function "createStripeUser" from my viewcontroller. It shows errors

Here is my viewcontroller :-

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import Stripe
import FirebaseFunctions
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
var paymentContext = STPPaymentContext()
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirm: UITextField!
@IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
           
alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){ (user, error) in if error == nil {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToHome", sender: self)
    
                }
 else{
   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
   let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                   
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
            }
      }
}
Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeUser").call(["email": email]) { (result, error) in **// error - Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'**
    
    if let error = error {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
   }
 }
```

Here is a screenshot of the errors

[image]

The functions are fully deployed in Firebase. why is it showing error?

Answer (score 0):

You've added the call to Cloud Functions after the closing `}` of your `signUpAction` function. This is much easier to see if you re-format your code:

```
func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else{
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){
            (user, error) in if error == nil {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToHome", sender: self)
            }
            else{
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

}
Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeUser").call(["email": email]) {
    (result, error) in **// error - Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'**
    if let error = error {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

My guess is that you want the `Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeUser")` call to be up above the `}` above it, so that it's part of the `signUpAction` function.

Comment: yes thats correct, the error went awym thanks. but still its not creating a stripe customer. I will ask a different question for that

Comment: upvoted your reply

Comment: Better yet. There's an upvote button to the left of my answer.